# Xslt: escape XML nodes when producing HTML

Tags: c#, html, xslt

I am using Microsoft's `System.Xml.Xsl` to create `HTML`. When transforming XML that contains escape sequences (e.g. `&lt;script&gt;`) into `HTML`, if the nodes are emitted as attributes, they are not escaped.

I would like to produce HTML where both attributes and nodes are escaped.

Xml sample:

```xml
<Contact>
  <Name>hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;</Name>
</Contact>
```

Xslt sample:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
<xsl:output method=""html"" indent=""yes"" doctype-system=""html"" />
<xsl:template match=""/"">
    <span data-title=""{{ 'title': '{/Contact/Name}' }}"">
        Name: <xsl:value-of select=""/Contact/Name""/>
        Input: <input type=""text"" value=""{/Contact/Name}""/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        var xml = @"<Contact><Name>hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;</Name></Contact>";
        var xslt = @"<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
<xsl:output method=""html"" indent=""yes"" doctype-system=""html"" />
<xsl:template match=""/"">
    <span data-title=""{{ 'title': '{/Contact/Name}' }}"">
        Name: <xsl:value-of select=""/Contact/Name""/>
        Input: <input type=""text"" value=""{/Contact/Name}""/>
    </span>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
";

        transform.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslt)));
        var settings = transform.OutputSettings.Clone();
        using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
        {
            var args = new System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList();
            transform.Transform(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)), args, writer);
            writer.Flush();
            output.Position = 0;
            Console.Write(new StreamReader(output).ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Actual result (with a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HpussX)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "html"><span data-title="{ 'title': 'hello <script>alert('!')</script>' }">
        Name: hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;
        Input: <input type="text" value="hello <script>alert('!')</script>"></span>
```

Expected / Desired result (with a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e3AOnA)):

```
<!DOCTYPE span SYSTEM "html">
<span data-title="{ 'title': 'hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;' }">
        Name: hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;
        Input: <input type="text" value="hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;" /></span>
```

Comment: If you use `xsl:output method="html" and let the XSLT processor serialize according to that it will serialize according to HTML rules (for an XSLT 1.0 processor like XslCompiledTransform that probably means roughly to what HTML 4.01 defined as text/html rules). What motivates the need for the desired output? The actual result should parse with a text/html parser.

Comment: The "unescaped" output does indeed parse in a standard browser. However, we have tooling that fetches this data via an AJAX call, parses out <script> tags and executes them.  So, I'm trying to pair xsl:output method="html" with XSS protections.

So a more precise question might be: how can I used XSLT to produce HTML, while escaping attributes exactly as XSLT does when producing XML?

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 3 with `xsl:output method="xhtml"`, possible with .NET framework using Saxon .NET 10.8 HE from Saxonica or with .NET 6/7 (Core) using SaxonCS 11 or 12 (commercial enterprise package) or using IKVM cross-compiled Saxon HE 11.4 Java, shown below, might give a result closer to your needs:

```
using net.sf.saxon.s9api;
using net.liberty_development.SaxonHE11s9apiExtensions;
using System.Reflection;

// force loading of updated xmlresolver (workaround until Saxon HE 11.5)
ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(Assembly.Load("org.xmlresolver.xmlresolver"));
ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(Assembly.Load("org.xmlresolver.xmlresolver_data"));

var processor = new Processor(false);

var xml = @"<Contact><Name>hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;</Name></Contact>";

var xslt = @"<xsl:stylesheet version=""3.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
<xsl:output method=""xhtml"" indent=""yes"" html-version=""5.0"" doctype-system=""about:legacy-compat"" omit-xml-declaration=""yes""/>
<xsl:template match=""/"">
    <span data-title=""{{ 'title': '{/Contact/Name}' }}"">
        Name: <xsl:value-of select=""/Contact/Name""/>
        Input: <input type=""text"" value=""{/Contact/Name}""/>
    </span>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
";

var xslt30Transformer = processor.newXsltCompiler().compile(xslt.AsSource()).load30();

var inputDoc = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(xml.AsSource());

using var resultWriter = new StringWriter();

xslt30Transformer.applyTemplates(inputDoc, processor.NewSerializer(resultWriter));

var result = resultWriter.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output is e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE span
  SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<span data-title="{ 'title': 'hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;' }">
   Name: hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;
   Input: <input type="text" value="hello &lt;script&gt;alert('!')&lt;/script&gt;"/></span>
```

Example project to show to use IKVM and Maven to include Saxon HE 11.4 Java is at https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonHE11NET7XHTMLOutputMethodExample1.